# Stack Explorer (Android app)

Tags: app, android

[image]

[image]

This Android app randomly selects pages from Stack Exchanges sites based on tags selected by the user, to help discover new interesting content and learn new things.
You can install it here:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.github.micpob.stackexplorer

Or by scanning the Qr code:

[image]

Github repo: https://github.com/micpob/Stack-Explorer

Comment: It seems to work well. Is the intention to press <kbd>Search</kbd> to fetch the next post? I was expecting a Next/Prev combo.